# Unique node validation is not working

Tags: 7, forms

I am using hook_node_presave to add this validation and its working fine for most of the scenario.

But sometime, this validation is not working so duplicate node is generated.

I am using following code
Using node_presave

```
/**
 * Implementing hook_node_validate
 */
function sample_changes_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'daily') {
    global $user;
    $userdata = user_load($user->uid);
    $cid = $userdata->field_profile_center['und'][0]['target_id'];
    $dated = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($node->field_daily_report_date["und"][0]["value"]));
    if (empty($node->nid) && (daily_report_exist($dated, $cid) == TRUE)) {
      drupal_set_message(t('Daily Report is already Created for this date.'), 'error');
      drupal_goto('node/add/daily-report');
    }
  }
}
```

Where daily_report_exist() is Boolean function to return TRUE/FALSE.

Using form_alter

```
/**
 * Implaments hook_form_alter.
 */
function sample_changes_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'daily_node_form') {
array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'daily_report_exist_validation');
}
}

function daily_report_exist_validation($form, &$form_state) {
   if (is_duplicate($form, $form_state)) {
      form_set_error('title', 'Daily Report is already Created for this date.');
    }
}
```

Where is_duplicate is Boolean function to return TRUE/FALSE same as daily_report_exist().
One thing i also notice, whenever validation failed and duplicate node is created, the node-created time difference is only 1 or 2 sec.

May be someone help me to fix this.

Comment: This is not a right way to apply a validation. Have you tried adding validate function using HOOK_form_alter ?

Comment: Yes, i also added same validation with 

array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'daily_report_exist_validation');

in HOOK_form_alter

Comment: Is that worked?

Comment: Yes both validation is working fine, individually  (in Presave and form alter).  Me and my QA team is also tested properly.

But after some time while we are checking the reports on production site we have some duplicate nodes. which is unexpected. That is the thing i want to figure out.

Comment: First thing is use form_set_error instead of drupal_set_message when you are applying the validation using form_alter.
Second thing is please make sure you are not resubmitting the node object 2 times.

Comment: Please let me know if above concern solves your problem. So, that I will post a proper solution for other users.

Comment: I updated my question what code i am using, and i am using hide_submit module to avoid resubmitting.

Comment: Ok, what is_duplicate()  doing? can you please share some code scenerio from there too?